# How to run a for loop in res.render on a get request in node.js? I am using hbs as view engine

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

In the following code I have to write description 1,2,3 and so on again and again, is there any way I can run a for loop to initialize all the variables?

I have to pass these values to hbs file which will show it in web page.

```
app.get('/:id/description', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  console.log(id);

  descriptionModel.findOne({"header":id}).then((DescriptionModel) => {
    if (DescriptionModel === null) {
      res.send('Sorry, the page you have requested does not exsist.');
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    res.render('index.hbs', {
      image: DescriptionModel.path,
      id: id,
      header: DescriptionModel.header,
      db_head_image_description1: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[0],
      db_head_image_heading1: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[0],
      db_head_image_description2: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[1],
      db_head_image_heading2: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[1],
      db_head_image_description3: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[2],
      db_head_image_heading3: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[2],
      db_head_image_description4: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[3],
      db_head_image_heading4: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[3],
      db_head_image_description5: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[4],
      db_head_image_heading5: DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[4],
      sub_heading: DescriptionModel.sub_heading,
      sub_heading_tagline: DescriptionModel.sub_heading_tagline,
      sub_heading_data: DescriptionModel.sub_heading_data,
      paralax_image_heading: DescriptionModel.paralax_image_heading,
      paralax_image_tagline: DescriptionModel.paralax_image_tagline,
      gallary_heading: DescriptionModel.gallary_heading,
      gallary_tagline: DescriptionModel.gallary_tagline,
    });
    // console.log(DescriptionModel);

  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it assigning the object to a variable, and then looping to get each description and image, like this:

```
app.get('/:id/description', (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;

  console.log(id);

  descriptionModel.findOne({"header":id}).then((DescriptionModel) => {
    if (DescriptionModel === null) {
      res.send('Sorry, the page you have requested does not exsist.');
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    const payload = {
      image: DescriptionModel.path,
      id: id,
      header: DescriptionModel.header,
      sub_heading: DescriptionModel.sub_heading,
      sub_heading_tagline: DescriptionModel.sub_heading_tagline,
      sub_heading_data: DescriptionModel.sub_heading_data,
      paralax_image_heading: DescriptionModel.paralax_image_heading,
      paralax_image_tagline: DescriptionModel.paralax_image_tagline,
      gallary_heading: DescriptionModel.gallary_heading,
      gallary_tagline: DescriptionModel.gallary_tagline,
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      payload[`db_head_image_description${i + 1}`] = DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[i]
      payload[`db_head_image_heading${i + 1}`] = DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[i]
    }

    res.render('index.hbs', payload);
    // console.log(DescriptionModel);

  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to start with you can define the object you're going to pass to `res.render` out side of `res.render`:

```
var myData = {};
res.render('index.hbs', myData);
```

You can also add key-value pairs to the object both as part of the declaration, and afterwards e.g:

```
var myData = {
    image: DescriptionModel.path,
    id: id
 };

 myData.header = DescriptionModel.header;

 res.render('index.hbs', myData);
```

At this point your object would have 3 properties: `image`, `id` and `header`.

You can also assign keys dynamically and use concatenation to create custom keys, e.g.

```
myData['db_head_image_description' + 1] = DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[0];
```

To construct the for loop, you'll want to use both dynamic keys and dynamic values. Assuming you have exactly 5 items and want to use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5, i++) {
  myData['db_head_image_description' + (i+1)] = DescriptionModel.header_image.image_description[0];
  myData['db_head_image_heading' + (i+1)] = DescriptionModel.header_image.image_heading[0];      
}
```

Comment: Only mistake in this code is in the line myData['db_head_image_description' + (i+1)]

String concatenation and integer addition will not work in same line. have to separate.